# I just installed Ubuntu 20.04 LTS whats the default password?

Tags: ubuntu, raspberry-pi, raspberry-pi3, ubuntu-20.04

This is a Raspberry pi 3 b+ running Ubuntu 20.04 LTS 32bit ([I downloaded from here](https://ubuntu.com/download/raspberry-pi)) and the screen says:

```
Ubuntu 20.04 ubuntu tty1

ubuntu login:
```

And I cant fine the username password. Also I am new to my Raspberry pi and linex.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Username and password are both "ubuntu" according to this: https://ubuntu.com/tutorials/how-to-install-ubuntu-on-your-raspberry-pi#4-boot-ubuntu-server

Comment: Note that you will be required to change this password on first usage!

Answer (score 16):

Also, it on a PI 4 using Ubuntu Server 20.04, even though it presents the login prompt you have to wait about 2 mins for the SSH authorisation to be completed.

And when you login it does a load of unattended updates as of writing it installed 26 packages and you cannot install anything else while it does these update

Comment: This was the key, I even reinstalled it thinking something went wrong. 
Waited a few minutes with a PI 2 and all the sudden started accepting the default user and pw. 
Thank you

Comment: this should be documented in the official docs